# Countdown loop for a 'raw_input' on the same line in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, input, countdown

I want to do a countdown loop for a normal `raw_input` were the normal `raw_input` don't change, only the numbers (in `raw_input`).

So, *Do you want to try again? [15-1]* outputs on one line and the numbers only change.

This is what I have so far and it doesn't work. So how would I do this?

```
while True:
            for i in range(15,-1,-1):
                con1=raw_input("\n Do you want to try again? " + str(i,))
            if i == 0:
                print "\n Thanks for playing!"
                exit(0)
            elif con1 == "no":
                print "\n Thanks for playing!"
                time.sleep(3)
                exit(0)
            elif con1 == "yes":
                break
```

Comment: This is a very difficult problem to solve, generally - `raw_input` really isn't capable of doing this, you'd need to use something like [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#module-curses).  There might be a possible hack to do it under `raw_input` with `threading`/`signal` but.. either way, you're headed down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Linux answer -- will not work on Windows

### Python 3

```
import select
import sys


def has_input(timeout=0.0):
    return select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)[0]


def getans(timeout=15):
    i = timeout
    max_num_length = len(str(timeout))
    while i:
        print("\rDo you want to try again? {:{}} ".format(i, max_num_length),
              end="", flush=True)
        i -= 1
        if has_input(1):
            return input()
    print()
    return None

print(getans())
```

### Python 2

```
import select
import sys


def has_input(timeout=0.0):
    return select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], timeout)[0]


def getans(timeout=15):
    i = timeout
    max_num_length = len(str(timeout))
    while i:
        sys.stdout.write("\rDo you want to try again? {:{}} ".format(i, max_num_length))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        i -= 1
        if has_input(1):
            return raw_input()
    print
    return None

print getans(5)
```

`getans` will return `None` on timeout, or the response otherwise. Theoretically, if a Windows version of `has_input` could be implemented, this could work on Windows, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! And yes i'm developing for/on Linux.